# What is a good valve that can automatically open/close wet food particles?

Tags: valve

Something that is 2-4 inches wide. Different types of valves like pinch, iris, butterfly, etc. Or something else?

Comment: please define `good` ... what are you trying to do? ... not really a robotics question

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Tommy, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.